# Laravel - need Regex to validate username, which prevents emoticon but allows special characters

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I want to validate username such a way that it should not accept the emoticons like :-),;-) etc.. but it should accept the special characters with the alphabets and numeric...tough one...

currently I have applied

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),array('username'=>'required|max:20|min:3');
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    Input::all(),
    array('username'=> array('required',
                             'max:20',
                             'min:3',
                             'Regex:/\A(?!.*[:;]-\))[ -~]+\z/')
    )
);
```

Note you can shorten the requirement like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    Input::all(),
    array('username'=> array('required',
                             'Regex:/\A(?!.*[:;]-\))[ -~]{3,20}\z/')
    )
);
```

Obviously, you need to complete with the other emiticons you want to forbid.

You can extend the allowed characters using `.` instead of `[ -~]` that limits the string to ascii characters.